# How do I disable screenshot from an android application?

Tags: android

How do I disable screenshot when my app is running on an android device? Is there any way to prevent someone from taking a screenshot?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257210/disable-screenshots-in-android-ics) may be helpful.

Comment: why is this question downvoted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257210/disable-screenshots-in-android-ics is essentially the same question asked 9 months later, and no one seems to have a problem with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [Flag Secure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) as a layout parameter flag.

Comment: Yes, it prevents screen recording as well. The screen would come as blank

Answer (score 2):

In the `onCreate()` **method**, add the **flag**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

before `setContentView();`