# How to prevent data on mobile screen from screenshot?

Tags: android, ios, screenshot

I want to create an app (iOS or Android does not matter now) that contains sensitive data and I don't want it to be spread via taking screenshots. It would be simply an article. Is there any way to hide data when user starts doing screenshot? For example listener on lock button down.

Comment: For Android, see [How do I disable screenshot from an android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11746364), I don't know about iOS though.

Comment: For iOS, no perfect solution i think, but u can make it some what difficult, by require the user to hold tap screen to show the content, and the snapshot key combine will make user lose touches, it doesnt help in screen capture and the person use another device to take screenshot ofcourse :p

Comment: may be not possible in iOS preventing user from taking screenshots and lets consider somehow you did it, but what about taking photos of screen from other camera?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara this may be solution for ios http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/ios-app-prevent-screen-capture

Comment: that can be workaround not perfect solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable screenshot from an android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746364/how-do-i-disable-screenshot-from-an-android-application)

Comment: Another iOS solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot