# How to disable screenshots in Android using Delphi XE5?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I know about [FLAG_SECURE as a way to disable the screen shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257210/disable-screenshots-in-android-ics) function of Android. How do I use it in FireMonkey / Delphi XE 5?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ANativeActivity_setWindowFlags` (this method change the window flags of the given activity.  Calls getWindow().setFlags() of the given activity)  passing the `AWINDOW_FLAG_SECURE` flag

try this sample

```
uses
 Androidapi.NativeActivity;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
 AWINDOW_FLAG_SECURE = $00002000;
begin
  ANativeActivity_setWindowFlags(PANativeActivity(System.DelphiActivity), AWINDOW_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
uses
  ...,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SharedActivity.getWindow.setFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_SECURE, TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_SECURE);
end;
```